# How to retrive each data of map object inside of firestore document for WEB

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firestore for a react application. But I am not getting how to show each data from a map object which is inside a document

[My firestore database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0jnp.png)

[The code I have written in react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AM1E.png)

[the result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKDfQ.png)

Please explain me as simple as possible

Comment: In your `console.log`, it says on line 31 but in your file, there's no `line 31`

Comment: I had removed comments from the code to take screenshot

Comment: By StackOverflow etiquette, you should take the time to enter and format your code *HERE*, not just links off-site.  Yes, it is work, but it's the work *you* trade for the *answers* you get.

Comment: How and where do you want to show the data from the document tags?
Do you want to render a list in HTML? if so,
What does the code you are showing in image 2 render?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.